# How to bind/access current row in findAll() inside a literal

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Is it possible to get the current value inside the `findAll()` method and set it inside a query literal?

Everything works fine if the MySQL version I am using is > 8

```
const mr = await req.db.models.MeterReading.findAll({
   where: { billing_month },
   include: [
      {
         model: req.db.models.Consumer,
         as: 'consumer',
         where: { route_no },
         required: true,
    ]
   },
  ],
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [literal(`(
        SELECT AVG(kwh_used), 
        FROM (
           SELECT kwh_used 
           FROM consumer_bill cb 
           WHERE cb.account_no_id = MeterReading.account_no_id 
           ORDER BY cutoff_month DESC 
           LIMIT 12
         ) as avg)
        `),
        'avg'
       ]],
      },
   });
```

Using the `MeterReading.account_no_id` in the literal query above works fine but when using MySQL version 5.7x, the `MeterReading.account_no_id` says that the column is Unknown. This doesnt work in a subquery.
How can I access the current row so that I can set it on the literal?
Something like this

```
[literal(`(
  SELECT AVG(kwh_used),
  FROM (
     SELECT kwh_used 
     FROM consumer_bill cb 
     WHERE cb.account_no_id = ${currentRow.account_no_id} 
     ORDER BY cutoff_month DESC 
     LIMIT 12
  ) as avg
)`),
'avg'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a type error in your SQL query `FROM`. I have added `AS` in the `FROM` line. Also, you can't use `currentRow` as that does not exist in the context of the query so I have changed it to `MeterReading` without the template string.

```
[
  sequelize.literal(`(
    SELECT AVG(kwh_used),
    FROM (
       SELECT kwh_used 
       FROM consumer_bill AS cb 
       WHERE cb.account_no_id = MeterReading.account_no_id
       ORDER BY cutoff_month DESC 
       LIMIT 12
    ) as avg
  )`),
  'avg'
]
```

Comment: That works fine in MySQL 8.x but not in MySQL 5.7.x
However, that will only work in MySQL 5.7.x without a subquery.

Comment: Within a literal you can only access the current table I think